# MySQL metadata search?

Tags: mysql, metadata

I'm coming from SQL Server background and getting into a project that uses MySQL. Is there any way to search the metadata of a MySQL database like there is with the Redgate SQL Search tool for SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you looking for? Most things will be in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA like discussed here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html

Comment: Yup, I had only found the show columns previously. Thanks